# What is a thread-safe ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, groovy

I'd like to read from a process's output and error streams and merge them into one stream of text. My program is in groovy and reads like this:

```
def mergeStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
process.waitForProcessOutput(mergeStream, mergeStream)
```

The problem is that ByteArrayOutputStream isn't thread safe and waitForProcessOutput() generates two threads which append to mergeStream. Is there a thread-safe variant that I can use? How else do you recommend that I control access to mergeStream? It looks like in practice characters are sometimes dropped with this implementation.

Comment: Have you considered ProcessBuilder's redirectErrorStream?

Comment: Yes it *is* thread safe, or rather all its methods are synchronized, and `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream()` makes your entire question redundant. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP - it's only "not a real question" if you know the answer - otherwise, it's a GREAT question!  The javadoc says nothing about it being synchronized - AFAICT, you have to dig in the source to find that out, and I never would have bothered (assuming it wasn't threadsafe, since the doc said nothing) had you not commented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `process.waitForProcessOutput()` takes an `OutputStream` as argument, you could simply use a custom implementation of `OutputStream` that has all its methods synchronized, and delegate to the corresponding method of a wrapped `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Just like `Collections.synchronizedList()` wraps another List into a synchronized List proxy.

EDIT:

That said, reading the source of ByteArrayOutputStream, all its methods are already synchronized, so it's already thread-safe. Your bug probably comes from elsewhere.